# access xml text node's content in matlab

Tags: matlab

Having an xml file like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Configuration>
  <Bla>
    BlaDiBla
  </Bla>
</Configuration>
```

I am wondering whether there is a more concise way to obtain 'BlaDiBla' using standard matlab (no additional toolbox) than this:

```
xmlfile = fullfile('C:\tttttt', 'Configuration.xml');
xDoc = xmlread(xmlfile);

char(xDoc.getElementsByTagName('Bla').item(0).getFirstChild.getData)
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [xml_io_tools](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/12907-xmliotools) from the File Exchange.

The syntax is:

```
  xmlfile = fullfile('C:\tttttt', 'Configuration.xml');
  struct = xml_load_any(xmlFile);
```

Comment: I try to make this future proof. Do you reckon I can easily use this 'external' code in conjunction with matlab coder to produce C code?

Comment: @csetzkorn, I have no idea. Unfortunately their code is p-code, which means that nobody can see it.